# RxSwift Chaining: What is a better way of writing this in Rxswift?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm very new to RxSwift. Very new. Normally to chain you without Rx, you put the next function inside a completion closure. My peers told me to use flatmap or our version of concatmap instead but never gave me an example. Can anybody convert this code with flatmap or the swift version of concatmap? Again I am very new, so please be gentle with the judgements.

```
 SVProgressHUD.show()
    params.address = address
    print(params)
    viewmodel
      .postSeekerAvatar(image: image).subscribe(onSuccess: {
//        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
//        SVProgressHUD.show()
        self.viewmodel
          .updateSeeker(withFirstName: params.firstName, lastName: params.lastName, isBusiness: params.isBusiness, abn: "none", address: params.address)
          .subscribe(onSuccess: {
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: SegueConstants.toProfileForm, sender: self)

      }) { (error) in
        SVProgressHUD.showDismissableError(with: error.message)
      }.disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
  }) { (error) in
    SVProgressHUD.showDismissableInfo(with: error.message)
  }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what you want is never have nested `subscribe` calls. Instead, you will transform the source observable values, sometimes into another value, other times with another observable.

```
SVProgressHUD.show()
params.address = address
print(params)
viewmodel
  .postSeekerAvatar(image: image)
  .flatMap {
    self.viewmodel
      .updateSeeker(withFirstName: params.firstName, lastName: params.lastName, isBusiness: params.isBusiness, abn: "none", address: params.address)
  }
  .subscribe(onSuccess: {
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: SegueConstants.toProfileForm, sender: self)
   }, onError: { (error) in
      SVProgressHUD.showDismissableError(with: error.message)
   })
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

So here, first `postSeekerAvatar` will be subscribed to, and everytime it pushes out a value, `updateSeeker` will also be subscribed to. If either of them errors out, the error closure will run.

Comment: I picked yours because I appreciate the explanation and its easier to understand for me as a newb.

Answer (score 1):

```
postSeekerAvatar() method should return a Single response 
Add showLoader/hideLoader method in BaseViewController. 

viewmodel
    .postSeekerAvatar(image: image) //Return Single<Response>
    .do(onSubscribed: presenter.showLoader)
    .do(onDispose: presenter.hideLoader)
    .asCompletable()
    .andThen(update(params: params))
    .subscribe()
    .disposeOnDeactivate(interactor: self)

//Returns a completable 
  private func update(params: Model) -> Completable {
    viewmodel
      .updateSeeker(
        withFirstName: params.firstName,
        lastName: params.lastName,
        isBusiness: params.isBusiness,
        abn: "none",
        address: params.address
    )
    return Completable.empty()
  }
```

Comment: Thanks man. I picked bottom answer because of explanation and it was easier to understand for me.